# Get the row group header on the right side of a tablix control

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, rdl

In Microsoft Reporting Services I'm trying to get a row group header to be on the right side of the tablix rather than the left.  Is this possible?

Steps taken:
Added a Table control to the report.  Gave it a dataset.
Right clicked on the detail record of the table and and chose "Add Group"->"Parent Group".
It puts the parent group on the left side of the table.

How can I get this on the right side?

(I tried to post a picture, but I don't have enough reputation yet)

What I'm trying to get is a cell that spans multiple rows so that I can show an image that pertains to a group of rows.  It would look something like this:  
  
                   
Row1 |>>>>>>>>>>>|  
Row2 |>>>Image>>>|  
Row3 |>>>>>>>>>>>|

Comment: The RTL will not work with your issue as the group is not considers a RTL candidate. Since reports are generally calculated left to right top to bottom I don't think there is a magic solutions for you. You could possibly add a left most column and modify the borders based on the current group value and the last group value to make it look like a column that runs the height of the row group. However, you will have to add another calculation to find the midpoint to place you group name label. I know its lame but I think that is what you are up against.

Comment: I dont understand your issue.  By definition a "row group header" extends across all columns of the tablix.  You can use any of the textboxes in that row to show your group heading data, left right or wherever.